# Неправильная запись при сохранении QJson

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5

Не могу найти чего то подобного на просторах Инета. Проблема в следующем: Читаю json файл, после просто сохраняю. Но значения получаются следующие(слева считанный , справа сохраненный)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же прикладываю код который сохраняет файл.

```
void JsonSetings::saveJson(SetupSettings setting, QString nameJson)
{
   QString val;
   QFile file;
   file.setFileName("test1.json");
   file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
   QJsonObject textObject;
   QJsonObject textObject2;
   textObject2[namesjson.mType] = setting.mType;
   textObject2[namesjson.mCounter] = setting.mCounter;
   textObject2[namesjson.mAlgorithm] = setting.mAlgorithm;
   textObject2[namesjson.mWork] = setting.mWork;
   textObject2[namesjson.mRoll] = setting.mRoll;
   textObject2[namesjson.mPitch] = setting.mPitch;
   textObject2[namesjson.mYaw] = setting.mYaw;
   textObject2[namesjson.mOwnSpeed] = setting.mOwnSpeed;
   textObject2[namesjson.mInstantSpeed] = setting.mInstantSpeed;
   textObject2[namesjson.mMask] = setting.mMask;
   textObject2[namesjson.mProtocol] = setting.mProtocol;
   textObject2[namesjson.mDriveSpeed] = setting.mDriveSpeed;
   textObject2[namesjson.mDriveDirection] = setting.mDriveDirection;
   textObject.insert("presets",textObject2);
   file.write(QJsonDocument(textObject).toJson());
}
```

Пожалуйста подскажите. Задача решена но мой Перфекционизм внутри не дает покоя.

Comment: Уже достал этот вопрос с точностью представления чисел с плавающей точкой...

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/112953/

Comment: @Harry меня мало интересует в данном вопросе точность) Как бы я понимаю что там и как это исправить. Если ты внимательно посмотришь на мой аск то ты увидешь что переменные(не уверен что они называются в json переменными) местами перепутаны.

Comment: Тогда в чем вопрос? числа проходят преобразование, вы получаете соответствующее представлению значение. Насчет порядка переменных - а разве в JSON порядок имеет значение? Они просто отсортированы по имени. Думаю, что используется `map`, вот  и имеем...

Answer (score 0):

Округляйте перед сохранением либо храните в строковом представлении.